# Accessing a webservice with R, RCurl, and SSOAP - 'Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where)'

Tags: r, soap, ubuntu-12.04

I am relatively new to using R and I am trying to access a webservice (AILUN) and I am getting and error which could be something fairly simple.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and R version 2.15.1

I have installed all of the prerequisites for the package 'SSOAP' from http://www.omegahat.org

Here is a step-by-step from the R command line. The files were downloaded from http://ailun.stanford.edu/webservice.php

```
getwd()
[1] "/home/gserver/Webservice"
library(SSOAP)
platformAnnotation_FindGPL <- function(array_send,ratio)
 {
 AILUN <- SOAPServer("http://ailun.stanford.edu/WebServ/Platform_Annotation.php")
 gpl_info <- .SOAP(AILUN, "platformAnnotation_FindGPL",templfile=array_send ,matchRatio=ratio, action="/Platform_Annotation.php")
 return (gpl_info)

 }
 con <- file("probe_ID.txt", "r")
 array1 <- readLines(con)
 ratio <- 30
 result <- platformAnnotation_FindGPL(array1,ratio)
Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Any advice or assistance is greatly appreciated!!